# Not able to show text in unescaped form by JSON.parse(response)

Tags: javascript, ace-editor

escaped string "**first line\r\n\tsecond line\r\n\t\t   working fine**"
using following code works fine but it is not working if setValue from server response

```
editor.setValue("first line\r\n\tsecond line\r\n\t\t working fine");
```

[image]

Not Working following code

```
$.ajax(settings).done(function (response) {
    editor.setValue(response);
});
```

[image]

Comment: this question is not related to ace, you could get the same results by doing console.log instead of setValue.

Comment: @auser Thanks, any suggestion to this problem

Comment: i suggest to reword your question, remove mention of ace, and add description of what code do you run on the server to send the response.
Depending on these things you can will need to either change the server side code to not escape or use `JSON.parse(response)`, or something like `response.replace(/\/([.])/, function(_, x) { if (x == "n") return "\n"; if (x == "t") return "\t"; ... }`